# Using jQuery to pass input value from one page, to the input vlaue on a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to user jQuery to accomplish this.  Any help will be much appreciated.  What I'm attempting to do...

On **Page 1** I have a small form. On **Page 2** I have a form allowing the user to search for values.

I'm creating a shortcut for users to type in a common search (last name) on **Page 1**, and then after they submit the form, it sends the data to **Page 2** AND also searches on **Page 2**.

#### Example:

User types in last name '*smith*' on **Page 1** and then hits the **send data** button. The data is then sent to **Page 2**. On **Page 2**, the last name field has been filled in AND the search button has been clicked.

---

#### Code for Page 1:

```
<!-- PAGE 1 -->
<form action="/page2" method="post">
    <div>
    <label>last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="last name">
    </div>

    <div>
     <input type="submit" value="send data">                
    </div>
</form>
```

#### Code for Page 2:

```
<!-- PAGE 2 -->
<form>
    <div>
    <label>last name search</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="last name">
    </div>

    <div>
     <input type="submit" value="search">                
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). `setItem` on Page 1 and then `getItem` on Page 2

Answer (score 2):

you can pass using query string

**Source PAge**

```
 $(function () {
        $("#submit").bind("click", function () {
            var url = "Page2.htm?lastName=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtName").val());
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
```

On destination page retrive the value of query string

```
var queryString = new Array();
    $(function () {
        if (queryString.length == 0) {
            if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (queryString["lastName"] != null) {
            var data = "";
            data += "<b>lastName:</b> " + queryString["name"];

        }
    });
```

**Update**

If you want to submit Page2 automatically then place following code

```
$('input[type="submit"]').one('click')
```

Comment: I believe you should also add `$('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click')` on the destination per the OPs request to have the search performed. Otherwise, excellent!

Comment: Hey, this works!  But... when adding `$('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click')` to the end of my code to make it search.  It keeps submitting the form multiple times.  Any idea why, or more importantly, make it only submit once?

Comment: use  $(document).one('click', function () {}